# Packaging packages for PYPI and setuptools

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi

Is it possible to have a package structure with the project files in the root?

Like so?

```
ProjectName/
    README
    setup.py
    file1.py
    file2.py
    file3.py
    docs/
```

If yes, then how?

I haven't been able to find a configuration option that can let me do this.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See if you can find an example of something with a similar structure and see how it was done.

Comment: @martineau I didn't find it in the docs and guides I looked at, everyone strongly suggests the structure mentioned above. I'll still take a look at a few packages to see if some where done this way. Nice tip. Thanks!